# Guice Module With Configurable Concrete Class

Tags: java, guice

If I have a client defined as follows:-

```
public interface Client {
    void send(String message);
}
```

And an implementation as follows:-

```
final class SocketClient {

    private Integer port;

    @Inject
    SocketClient(Integer port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(String message) {
        System.out.println("Sending message:- "+message+" to port "+port);
    }
}
```

How would I use Guice to instantiate multiple instances of the SocketClient, each connecting to different ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution that comes to mind is to create a `SocketClientFactory` interface that looks like

```
interface SocketClientFactory {
  SocketClient createForPort(int port);
}
```

and then get factory instances using the [assisted injection extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

Comment: The assisted injection looks like what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement something like a singleton PortAllocator which kept track of the ports it had already allocated. You could then inject that into your client:

```
@Inject
SocketClient(PortAllocator portAllocator) {
  this.port = portAllocator.allocatePort();
}
```

PortAllocator might look something like:

```
@Singleton
class PortAllocator {
  private int nextPort = 1234;

  int allocatorPort() {
    return nextPort++;
  }
}
```

You could de-couple using an interface if you liked. You might want to think about thread-safety too.

You might argue that you're not getting much out of Guice here, but you are getting the in-built singleton state management and the lack of statics make testing easy.

Comment: Good answer but I know the ports I want to connect too.

Comment: Yes, I interpreted your question slightly differently. AssistedInject or the Factory pattern does look like the right approach.